# customizing odata output from asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm using the new ASP.NET webapi odata (version 4.0.0 last published 27/2/2013 according to Nuget)

Basically I'm doing it as described here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api

I'm publishing my data transfer objects and the odata atom pub feed is created but I'd like to have some more control over it. Mainly I'd like to be able to do the following:

- decide what goes on the title, author and updated elements for the feed
- decide whether or not to have the edit links
- change what is shown in `<category term="X"`and in `m:type` in sub properties that are classes in my application. Currently they expose the c# class names with the full namespace but I don't want to expose this.

Thanks.

Comment: We are working on adding extensiblity hooks to the ODataMediaTypeFormatter right now. You should be able to customize atom metadata after that.

Comment: And regarding the optional edit links, there is a codeplex [work item](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/501) open for it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The OData media type formatter is more extensible now. Samples follow.

1) decide what goes on the title, author and updated elements for the feed

```cs
public class AtomMetadataFeedSerializer : ODataFeedSerializer
{
    public AtomMetadataFeedSerializer(IEdmCollectionTypeReference edmType, ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        : base(edmType, serializerProvider)
    {
    }

    public override ODataFeed CreateODataFeed(IEnumerable feedInstance, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
    {
        ODataFeed feed = base.CreateODataFeed(feedInstance, writeContext);
        feed.Atom().Title = new AtomTextConstruct { Kind = AtomTextConstructKind.Text, Text = "My Awesome Feed" };
        return feed;
    }
}

public class CustomSerializerProvider : DefaultODataSerializerProvider
{
    public override ODataEntrySerializer CreateEdmTypeSerializer(IEdmTypeReference edmType)
    {
        if (edmType.IsCollection() && edmType.AsCollection().ElementType().IsEntity())
        {
            // feed serializer
            return new AtomMetadataFeedSerializer(edmType.AsCollection(), this);
        }

        return base.CreateEdmTypeSerializer(edmType);
    }
}
```

And register the custom serializer provider using,

```cs
config.Formatters.InsertRange(0, ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create(new CustomSerializerProvider(), new DefaultODataDeserializerProvider()));
```

2) customize edit links

```cs
public class CustomEntityTypeSerializer : ODataEntityTypeSerializer
{
    public CustomEntityTypeSerializer(IEdmEntityTypeReference edmType, ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        : base(edmType, serializerProvider)
    {
    }

    public override ODataEntry CreateEntry(EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
    {
        ODataEntry entry = base.CreateEntry(entityInstanceContext, writeContext);
        if (notProduceEditLinks)
        {
            entry.EditLink = null;
        }

        return entry;
    }
}

public class CustomSerializerProvider : DefaultODataSerializerProvider
{
    public override ODataEntrySerializer CreateEdmTypeSerializer(IEdmTypeReference edmType)
    {
        if (edmType.IsEntity())
        {
            // entity type serializer
            return new CustomEntityTypeSerializer(edmType.AsEntity(), this);
        }

        return base.CreateEdmTypeSerializer(edmType);
    }
}
```

and register the custom serializer provider as above.

We still don't support scenario 3 i.e aliasing type names and namespaces.

Comment: Where is ODataFeedSerializer. I have the latest Nuget package for Microsoft ASP.NET Web API OData (v:4.0.1) It doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: It should be there in our nightly builds. You can refer to Henrik's blog post on how to use our nightly builds [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/06/01/using-nightly-asp-net-web-stack-nuget-packages-with-vs-2012-rc.aspx). The myget feed url is http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/

Comment: Does version 7 have documentation on ODataMEdiaTypeFormmater? Create() method has changed as well as the ODataMediaTypeFormatter. No longer contains MessageWriterSettings.MediaTypeResolver so I cannot figure out how tie my custom formatter to my specific media type.