# Prevent null values from being emitted in a WebAPI OData v4 service

Tags: c#, json, odata, asp.net-web-api

I'm running an WebAPI OData v4 service and I don't want null values to be emitted. For example, when I request a `User` object, the following is returned:

```
"value": [
{
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Smith",
  "EmailAddress": "john@smith.com",
  "PasswordHash": null,
  "PhoneNumber": "11234567890",
  "Website": null,
  "Id": "dac9706a-8497-404c-bb5a-ca1024cf213b"
}
```

Since the `PasswordHash` and `Website` fields are null, I'd like them to not be included in the output. I've tried the following lines in the application's Register block, but none of them work:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

Below is the full contents of the Register method. I'm using the Newtonsoft Json package to handle the JSON serialization.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "UploadComplete",
            routeTemplate: "UploadFiles/Complete",
            defaults: new { controller = "UploadFiles", action = "Complete" }
        );

        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.EntitySet<Address>("Addresses");
        builder.EntitySet<Assignment>("Assignments");
        builder.EntitySet<Course>("Courses");
        builder.EntitySet<File>("Files");
        builder.EntitySet<UploadFile>("UploadFiles");
        builder.EntitySet<Organization>("Organizations");
        builder.EntitySet<Submission>("Submissions");
        builder.EntitySet<Term>("Terms");
        builder.EntitySet<User>("Users");

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());

        // Neither of these lines work.
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    }
```

Comment: I think you can derive from ODataEntityTypeSerializer.cs, and remove the "null" property from the `Properties` in ODataEntry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Brian Rogers for pointing me in the right direction, I ended up overriding `ODataEntityTypeSerializer` like so:

```
public override ODataEntry CreateEntry(SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)
{
    ODataEntry entry = base.CreateEntry(selectExpandNode, entityInstanceContext);

    // Remove any properties which are null.
    List<ODataProperty> properties = new List<ODataProperty>();
    foreach (ODataProperty property in entry.Properties)
    {
        if (property.Value != null)
        {
            properties.Add(property);
        }
    }

    entry.Properties = properties;
    return entry;
}
```

And then I used code from [RaghuRam-Nadiminti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132667/customizing-odata-output-from-asp-net-web-api) to implement a `CustomSerializerProvider` class which I could then use in `Register`.

Comment: Nicely done.  Thanks for coming back to post your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Although Web API iteself uses the Json.Net serializer, the [MediaTypeFormatter for Web API OData](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OData/src/System.Web.Http.OData/OData/Formatter/ODataMediaTypeFormatter.cs) uses its own internal serializer which is *not* Json.Net.  Therefore, changing the Json.Net serializer settings in the configuration will not have any effect on OData.  However, it does appear that you can implement your own [`ODataSerializerProvider`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Formatter/Serialization/ODataSerializerProvider.cs) and [`ODataDeserializerProvider`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Formatter/Deserialization/ODataDeserializerProvider.cs) classes to get OData to use Json.Net.  See [JSON.NET as a WebAPI 2 OData serializer vs ODataMediaTypeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20656229/10263) for a starting point.