# Deserializing Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date

Tags: c#, json.net, odata, converters

I am using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialize an object, and the routine came across a date field that it did not know how to handle.  Here is the error:

```
Error converting value \"2018-08-22\" to type 
'System.Nullable`1[Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date]'. Path 'value[3].actualclosedate'
```

Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date is a struct object used by Microsoft to hold date-only data.

I am trying to build a custom converter for this type of field, but not getting it to work properly.

Here is my converter code:

```
public class EdmDateConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return objectType == typeof(global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date); }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return (global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date)global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date.Parse(reader.ReadAsString());
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string myDate = ((global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date)value).Year.ToString("D4");
        myDate += "-";
        myDate += ((global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date)value).Month.ToString("D2");
        myDate += "-";
        myDate += ((global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date)value).Day.ToString("D2");

        writer.WriteValue(myDate);
    }
}
```

And here is how I tried to link it into the global list of converters:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
            {
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                settings.Converters.Add(new EdmDateConverter());
                //settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                return settings;
            };
```

I am getting the same error as before, so either the converter is not getting added correctly or I don't have it written properly.

Can anyone give me some guidance on this issue?

Comment: First, why don't you use the OData client? Second, why use a special converter? `YYYY-MM-DD` is the default date format used by Json.NET. Just use a `DateTime` type for your property

Comment: I'm not sure whether OData uses Json.NET, see [JSON.NET as a WebAPI 2 OData serializer vs ODataMediaTypeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20656229).  And even if it does, it might not use the global serializer settings.

Comment: See also [Prevent null values from being emitted in a WebAPI OData v4 service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33192231) where an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33192803) by [Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers) states, *the MediaTypeFormatter for Web API OData uses its own internal serializer which is not Json.Net.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message indicates that the member type being deserialized is a `Nullable<Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date>`, but your [`CanConvert`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanConvert.htm) method is not accounting for the possibility that `objectType` might be [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/).

You can fix this by modifying `CanConvert` as follows:

```
public class EdmDateConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) 
    {
        var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType;
        return type == typeof(global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date); 
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.SkipComments().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        return (global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date)global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date.Parse(reader.ReadAsString());
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string myDate = ((global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date)value).Year.ToString("D4");
        myDate += "-";
        myDate += ((global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date)value).Month.ToString("D2");
        myDate += "-";
        myDate += ((global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date)value).Day.ToString("D2");

        writer.WriteValue(myDate);
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader SkipComments(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment && reader.Read())
            ;
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- It is also necessary for check for a `null` token in `ReadJson()`.  `WriteJson()`, on the other hand, is never called for a `null` value; instead Json.NET writes `null` automatically.
- There may be other issues with your code since your question does not include sample JSON, deserialization code or c# classes.

Comment: Thanks to all who answered.  dbc, dead on with the nullable issue in canconvert.  I had thought about that, but had no idea on how to implement it.  Would not have gotten that syntax without your help.  The routine is working perfectly now.