# WebAPI OData Datetime serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-web-api, odata

I need to change the way OData serializes `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`.

Currently we are using `Microsoft.AspNet.OData 5.9.0`

By default the format is most likely `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFzzz`, but I need to have constant number of digits so something like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffzzz`.

So far I've learned that WebApi OData does not use `Newtonsoft.Json` for Json serialization as WebApi does and that it's pretty hard to find some examples of how to change serializer behavior.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think what you need is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15400048/4067893
This is: you need to implement a custom ODataEntityTypeSerializer.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good start, but it doesn't say, how to change serialization behavior for primitive types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this via creating a customized payload coverter,

1. Implement a class extends class ODataPayloadValueConverter
2. Override method public override object ConvertToPayloadValue(object value, IEdmTypeReference edmTypeReference)
3. Have a check like this in the method
   if (value is DateTimeOffSet)
   {
       return "CustomziedString";
   }
4. Register into your model via setting like 
   model.SetPayloadValueConverter(converter);

Then the payload in response will be shown the DateTimeOffset in your customized way.