# Control JSON datetime serialization in OData web api

Tags: json, odata

I have a OData web api, which by default serializes datetimes in JSON format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+HH:mm (eg 2021-08-31T12:00:00+10:00 - midday @ GMT +10 hours).  I'd like to serialize and deserialize this as yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+HH (eg 2021-08-31T12:00:00+10).

I'm using OData for asp.net core: Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData with DI.
I've looked at [WebAPI OData Datetime serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839672/webapi-odata-datetime-serialization), however, it's using ODataPayloadValueConverter which is part of ODataLib library.

I don't want to create a wrapper model with string properties, as this is not only ugly, but I'm using EF and it won't convert a C# conversion method to SQL in order to utilize OData's querying functionality.

What I'm looking for is a way of injecting a custom serializer into the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData middleware layer.

Comment: Why are you asking for this? You're asking to introduce a serious bug. Offsets aren't whole hours. India is +5:30. Besides, breaking *standard* formats is a serious bug in itself. In OData dates [*must* be in that specific format](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part3-csdl-complete.html#_Toc406398065), otherwise you don't have OData. You have some custom format nobody else can understand or process

Comment: Yes, you're right.  This is to support the devexpress react scheduler behaviour: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#dateSerializationFormat.  '***x' serializes in this format.  It looks like a bug to me.  I've also raised this as a ticket with devexpress, to have the serialization reflect HH:mm in the timezone.  That is the preferred solution.

Comment: That's not what that link says. The ISO8601 format is the standard in JSON as well. If a major component vendor had such a huge bug people would have noticed and complained several years ago. The DataGrid would be unable to display any date value except local dates

Comment: I agree.  Hence the ticket I've raised with DevExpress.  Perhaps there's something I'm doing wrong in configuring the scheduler... it's odd behaviour.  Another solution, which appears equally ugly, could be for me to remove timezone completely.  The devexpress control provides serialization in the format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" as well.  Although that would satisfy my business requirements, it will also break the OData standard.